# Apply a function across multiple columns and write to a csv in R

Tags: r, function, loops

R beginner here, my question is: How do I change this function so that it can be used across all my time periods without copying and pasting the function over and over? The time periods are indicated in the function by the `from = X$pre.start1[i]` and `to = X$pre.start2[i]` arguments.  I would like to have all the results end up in a single .csv file as well. Is that possible?
I know this function works and I have used it in the past by copying it and changing the time periods but with multiple spreadsheets with data like this it is tedious to apply this way. So I am looking to modify it so that I am not copying and pasting hundreds of times.

The function:

```
ADIanalyzeFUN <- function(X) {
  adianalyzeFUN <- function(X, i){
    r <- read_wave(X$sound.files[i], from = X$pre.start1[i], to = X$pre.start2[i])
    soundfile.adi <- acoustic_diversity(r)
    return(soundfile.adi$adi_left)
    return(soundfile.adi$adi_right)
  }
  output <- vector("logical", ncol(X)) 
  for (i in seq_along(X$sound.files)) {     
    output[[i]] <- adianalyzeFUN(X, i)
  }
  
  X$adi.values.pre1to2 <-output
  write.csv(X, "/media/parks/Seagate Portable Drive 2 (2tb)/Parks/2021 Threat Experiment/ADI index values/ADI01.csv", row.names = TRUE)
}
```

Below is a sample of the data
Each column is a list of times in seconds and I am applying the function to the wave file between one time and the next eg between pre.start1 and pre.start2.

````
  pre.start1 pre.start2 pre.start3 pre.start4 pre.start5 pre.start6 pre.start7 pre.start8 pre.start9 pre.start10 pre.end duringpb.start1
1       2304       2364       2424       2484       2544       2604       2664       2724       2784        2844    2904            2964
2       1386       1446       1506       1566       1626       1686       1746       1806       1866        1926    1986            2046
3       1680       1740       1800       1860       1920       1980       2040       2100       2160        2220    2280            2340
4       1553       1613       1673       1733       1793       1853       1913       1973       2033        2093    2153            2213
5       1661       1721       1781       1841       1901       1961       2021       2081       2141        2201    2261            2321
6       1728       1788       1848       1908       1968       2028       2088       2148       2208        2268    2328            2388
  duringpb.end1 duringpb.start2 duringpb.end2 duringpb.start3 duringpb.end3 duringpb.start4 duringpb.end4 duringpb.start5 duringpb.end5
1          3024            3084          3144            3204          3264            3324          3384            3444          3504
2          2106            2166          2226            2286          2346            2406          2466            2526          2586
3          2400            2460          2520            2580          2640            2700          2760            2820          2880
4          2273            2333          2393            2453          2513            2573          2633            2693          2753
5          2381            2441          2501            2561          2621            2681          2741            2801          2861
6          2448            2508          2568            2628          2688            2748          2808            2868          2928```

Thanks for any help!

I would like the output to be something like:
 X pre.start1-pre.start2 pre.start2-pr.estart3 pre.start3-pre.start4
1                  0.86                  0.56                  0.89
2                  0.27                  0.09                  0.03
3                  0.18                  0.10                  0.55
4                  0.39                  0.52                  0.74
5                  0.14                  0.17                  0.97
6                  0.91                  0.64                  0.71
````

Comment: What exactly do you want? Looping over `from = X$pre.start1[i], to = X$pre.start2[i]` to `X$pre.start9[i], to = X$pre.start10[i]`? Or something else? I'm still struggling with your exact problem. So basically it's up to the question: How does your expected output look like based on the data shown? If your example data is too large, please make a smaller example.

Comment: Sorry, Let me clarify. I would like to repeatedly apply the 'acoustic_diversity(r)' function to the time periods in order: 'from = X$pre.start1[i], to = X$pre.start2[i]' through ' from = X$pre.start10[i], to = X$pre.end[i]' so that I end up with a spread sheet that has index values from all the periods. I have added an example in to my original question

Comment: (1) It's better to put the clarification into your question. (2) Your question is not reproducible: `read_wave(X$sound.files[i], ...)` refers to objects we can access, `acoustic_diversity()` is an unknown function (at least for me). Try to adjust your question and reduce it to the neccessary parts. (3) It's better to post data as `dput(head(YourDataFrame))` output. The table shown above is quite cumbersome to import into R.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `purrr` package and their map variant called `map2_df()` (this package is a part of the `Tidyverse`)

Your example isn't easily reproducible, so here's an example of taking 2 first columns from the `iris` dateset and constructing a dataframe (a `tibble` in this case) with the sum for each row and putting it into one dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% tibble 
#> # A tibble: 150 × 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # … with 140 more rows

map2_df(
  .x = iris$Sepal.Length,
  .y = iris$Sepal.Width,
  .f = ~ tibble("sum" = sum(c(.x, .y)))
  )
#> # A tibble: 150 × 1
#>      sum
#>    <dbl>
#>  1   8.6
#>  2   7.9
#>  3   7.9
#>  4   7.7
#>  5   8.6
#>  6   9.3
#>  7   8  
#>  8   8.4
#>  9   7.3
#> 10   8  
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That looks like it would help with part of the problem and I will utilize this for aggregating the data. I am still stuck on how to apply the function across multiple time periods without  copying the entire code at least 10 times. Any suggestions on making the code more easily reproducible?

Comment: use .x and .y arguments as your data points (begin and end date) and map through those like so `map2(.x = start_time, .y = end_time, .f = \(x, y){your_function_for_time_periods(x, y)}`. For reproducible examples, check the `repex` package.